# p:calendar mindate maxdate not working with converter

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have PrimeFaces calendar with custom converter. It doesn't seems to take the maxdate and mindate attributes when I use converter.

It works with PF 5 but doesn't work with PF 6.x.

```
<p:outputLabel>Date</p:outputLabel>
                    <p:calendar size="12" maxlength="10" showOn="button"
                        value="#{testHandler.cal}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
                        mindate="#{testHandler.today}"
                        maxdate="#{testHandler.future12Months}" navigator="true"></p:calendar>


                    <p:outputLabel>Another Date</p:outputLabel>
                    <p:calendar size="12" maxlength="10" showOn="button"
                        value="#{testHandler.cal}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
                        mindate="#{testHandler.today}"
                        maxdate="#{testHandler.future12Months}" navigator="true"
                        converter="CalendarConverter"></p:calendar>
```

[Calendar with converter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVkMj.png)

[Calendar without converter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xwvi.png)

Comment: And what were the results when you tried PF7?

Comment: Same result. Nothing changes with PF 7.